# How to log queries inside PLPGSQL with inlined parameter values

Tags: postgresql, logging, prepared-statement, plpgsql, sql-execution-plan

When a statement in my `PLPGSQL` function (Postgres 9.6) is being run I can see the query on one line, and then all the parameters on another line. A 2-line logging. Something like:

```
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1=$1 AND field2=$2 ...    
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '-767197682', $2 = '234324' ....
```

Is it possible to log the entire query in pg_log *WITH* the parameters already replaced in the query and log it in a *SINGLE* line?

Because this would make it much easier to copy/paste the query to reproduce it in another terminal, especially if queries have dozens of parameters.

Comment: I don't think you can change the logging format. Rather than trying to substitute the parameters yourself, it'd be easier to run the query via [`PREPARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) / [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-execute.html). You should be able to turn these log lines into a runnable script with some fairly simple regex.

Comment: @NickBarnes, Thanks. Seems that a script would be the only solution.

Comment: You can add, if necessary, [`RAISE NOTICE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) (or similar) in your code, and Log whatever necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind this: PL/pgSQL treats SQL statements like ***prepared statements*** internally.

First: With default settings, there is ***no*** logging of SQL statements inside PL/pgSQL functions at all. Are you using [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html)?

- [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23357/3684)

The first couple of invocations in the same session, the SPI manager (Server Programming Interface) generates a fresh execution plan, based on *actual* parameter values. Any kind of logging should report parameter values *inline*.

Postgres keeps track and after a couple of invocations in the current session, if execution plans don't seem sensitive to actual parameter values, it will start reusing a generic, cached plan. Then you should see the generic plan of a prepared statements with `$n` parameters (like in the question).

Details in the [chapter "Plan Caching" in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING).

You can observe the effect with a simple demo. In the same session (not necessarily same transaction):

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl AS
SELECT id FROM generate_series(1, 100) id;

PREPARE prep1(int) AS
SELECT min(id) FROM tbl WHERE id > $1;

EXPLAIN EXECUTE prep1(3);  -- 1st execution
```

You'll see the actual value:

```
Filter: (id > 3)
```

```sql
EXECUTE prep1(1);  -- several more executions
EXECUTE prep1(2);
EXECUTE prep1(3);
EXECUTE prep1(4);
EXECUTE prep1(5);

EXPLAIN EXECUTE prep1(3);
```

Now you'll see a `$n` parameter:

```
Filter: (id > $1)
```

So you can get the query with parameter values *inlined* on the first couple of invocations in the current session.

Or you can use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`, because, [quoting the manual:](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684)

> Also, there is **no plan caching** for commands executed via `EXECUTE`.
> Instead, the command is always planned each time the statement is run.
> Thus the command string can be dynamically created within the function
> to perform actions on different tables and columns.

That can actually affect performance, of course.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL Stored Procedure Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684)